# Linux on My MacBook Pro - Want to erase Linux and reinstall macOS

Tags: mac, usb, unix

I currently am running Kali Linux on my laptop. Currently I need to sell my laptop for some extra cash. I am looking to reinstall Mac OS, so it can be ready for sale. Keeping my current files is not an issue as they have backed up elsewhere.
I have looked up some options but do not know what one would be best.

bootable usb?
mac os disk install?

Thanks

Comment: Precisely what model? Pretty much anything since 2011 can use [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT204904)

Comment: its a macbook pro from 2014

Comment: would I be able to get that at start up with it 100% running linux?

Comment: Yes, it should boot from firmware, even with a totally blank drive in it.

Comment: Yay for Kali Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to erase and reinstall macOS:

> ### Start up from macOS Recovery
>
> 1. macOS Recovery installs different versions of macOS depending on the key combination you use while starting up. Turn on or restart your
>      Mac, then immediately hold down one of these combinations:
>      [image]
>
> 2.Release the keys when you see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
>
> ### Erase your startup disk
>
> If you need to erase your startup disk, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Select Disk Utility from the utilities window of macOS Recovery, then click Continue.
> 2. Select your device or volume in the sidebar of Disk Utility.
> 3. Click the Erase button or tab.
> 4. Complete these fields:
>
>    - Name: Enter a name for your disk, such as "Macintosh HD".
>    - Format: Choose Mac OS Extended (Journaled) or APFS.
>    - Scheme (if available): Choose GUID Partition Map.
> 5. Click Erase to begin erasing your disk.
> 6. When done, quit Disk Utility to return to the utilities window. You're now ready to install macOS.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Install macOS
>
> 1. Choose Reinstall macOS (or Reinstall OS X) from the utilities window.
> 2. Click Continue, then follow the onscreen instructions. You'll be asked to select your disk. If you don't see it, click Show All Disks.
> 3. Click Install. Your Mac restarts after installation is complete.
>
> If you erased your disk before installing, or you installed on an
>   external drive or other new disk, your Mac restarts to a setup
>   assistant.
>
> - If you're keeping your Mac, complete the setup assistant with your own information.
> - If you're selling or giving away your Mac, press Command-Q to quit the setup assistant without completing the setup steps. Then click
>     Shut Down. When the new owner starts up the Mac, they can use their
>     own information to complete setup.

---

**More more information: [What to do before you sell or give away your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065)**